# Ubuntu Server - Unable to remove package

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, webmin

I'm unable to remove package.

```
[sudo] password for admin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  webmin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 173 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 143102 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing webmin (1.900) ...
dpkg: error processing package webmin (--remove):
 cannot remove '/usr/share/webmin/qmailadmin/stop.cgi': Bad message
Errors were encountered while processing:
 webmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I looked in to the permissions, I see the following:

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/webmin/qmailadmin/stop.cgi': Bad message
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 29 21:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 111 root root 12288 Jan 29 20:54 ..
-?????????   ? ?    ?        ?            ? stop.cgi
```

How to fix this.

Comment: Please show the output of `mount` to allow more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `umount` the file system that contains the corrupt file and check it with `fsck` (or probably `e2fsck`, depending on your file system type).

If you cannot `umount` the file system because it's in use, you might have to boot a live system from CD/DVD/USB to do the `fsck`

Comment: I already did fsck. No luck so far.

Comment: @Mov Did you unmount the file system for fsck?  Maybe you have to force the check. Please show the `fsck` command and its output in your question. ...and the `mount` output as already suggested. If you unsuccessfully tried other things, add this information to your question.

Comment: I did force fsck at boot and rebooted the system. and no errors reported at that time. AFAIK, at the boot time, when you run fsck, filesystem is always in unmounted state. I assuming you are not referring to the single user run level after the boot.  May be I need to nuke the filesystem?

Comment: Please add all important information **to the question**. This way it's easier for everyone to understand the problem. You could try to boot a live system and see if it shows the same problem for the affected file and if yes try to run `fsck` from there. If you only write what you did without showing the exact command and output it is not possible to check for errors or give hints for better commands.